# Why would combining this RAM cause games (and only games?) to be slower?

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard

I have two sticks of RAM labeled ADATA `AD3U1600W4G11-B DDR3 1600(11) 4GX8    U-DIMM 10242397`

I also have one stick of RAM labeled SKhynix `4GB 2Rx8 PC3-12800U-11-12-B1 HMT351U6CFR8C-PB NO AA 1321`

There's some other information on the labels in these pictures:
[image: adata RAM]
[image: SKhynix RAM]

When I put all of these in my [motherboard](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/m78_hmm.pdf) (labeled A75M), it works fine, turns on, and most programs actually work just fine. Better, even.

However, it makes games like Starbound completely unplayable because it lags so terribly bad.

Any clue why that is?

Comment: Based on the specification of the modules they both identical frequency and timing.  So your problem is unlikely due to the use of either memory module.

Comment: I also followed the guide I linked - interestingly enough what *it* says is DIMM 1-4 is different than the printing on my motherboard.

Comment: If you want help you will have to provided that page from the manual which labels which slots are which channels and then a corresponding picture of your actual motherboard if you want assistance in this matter.